# I forgot how to solve two systems of equations, I am trying to solve these two equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

$1 = \sqrt{r^{2}-(1-a)^{2}}$ and $2 = \sqrt{r^{2}-(4-a)^{2}}$.

Comment: Try squaring, then subtract one from the other to eliminate r, then....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1=r^2-1+2a-a^2$$
$$4=r^2-16+8a-a^2$$
so $r^2=2-2a+a^2=20-8a+a^2 \iff 6a=18 \iff a=3 $
$$r^2=5 \iff r=\sqrt{5} \lor r=-\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Not so relevant to this question, but just for the record, when we square equations aspart of the solving process we can create additional solutions (because the sign of the square root can be ambiguous) - always good to check solutions by substituting back into the original equation.